# Abstracting part of a .m file objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an action in `someViewController.m` called `sendMessage`

I would like to somehow called `sendMessage` from `anotherViewController.m`, but would like to include the method in `anotherViewController.m` without `copy/pasting` the code. Should I use a category for this? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

A **UIViewController** category is probably ideal if `sendMessage:` is not specific to someViewController. Otherwise you could always have **AnotherViewController** be a subclass of someViewController.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really interested in overriding the methods and adding additional methods go for category. If you want the default implementation also you must do subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

You have two other options besides those given:
1) create class MessageViewController with SomeViewController and AnotherViewController as subclasses, and put sendMessage method in MessageViewController parent class. (Usual convention is that class names are capitalized, instances/variables are not.(
2) define a protocol and declare both classes as supporting that protocol. It's very useful to understand how to do this. See:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: A handy advantage of protocols is that some other object then can have a member which is the right kind of reference, declared as

    id <MyProtocol> messageReceiver;